# Search and concatenate Landsat bands with Python

Tags: python, remote-sensing, landsat, orfeo-toolbox

I have a number of Landsat geotiff (*.TIF) file in a folder. The problem is simple, I need to search certain Landsat bands from that list and make a composite tif image. I am using Orfeo Toolbox's CLI utility. So far I have this

```py
import os
dir = "C:\Documents and Settings\Landsat_image"
def fileList():
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir):
        for tifFile in filenames:
            for i in range(3):
                if tifFile.find('B' + str(i)) != -1 and tifFile.endswith('.TIF'):
                    inputImages = os.path.join(dir, tifFile)
                    outputImages = os.path.join(root, tifFile) + '_concat.tif'
                    process = os.system(
                    'otbcli_ConcatenateImages -il %s -out %s' % (inputImages, outputImages))
print fileList()
```

The `otbcli_ConcatenateImages` needs the inputs in following format

`otbcli_ConcatenateImages -il GomaAvant.png GomaApres.png -out otbConcatenateImages.tif`

But maybe it is getting multiple entries for `out`.

`ERROR: Invalid number of value for: "out", invalid number of values 4`

I know the problem is silly but I am still a noob.

Comment: Can you please explain what "concatenating" the bands does and which bands you combine? I'm guessing you are working in a folder containing the different bands of a single scene?

Comment: 'Concatenating' is Orfeo's version of layer stacking. Yes the folder contains Landsat bands of same scene some of which I don't need.

Comment: Is using GDAL an option? It is the most widely used Python API for such cases and also provides command line tools like `gdalbuildvrt` and `gdal_merge` (both with the `-separate` flag) that would do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I know OTB will eventually come back to GDAL at some point, but I am tempted to use Python's batch processing capability with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Kersten and Matej for you help. After deliberate attempt my code seem not to behave correctly. So I had to rewrite completely and came up with this,

```py
import os
import glob

def concatLandsat(dir):
    band = 3  # The number of desired bands goes here
    inputTif = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, "*.TIF")))[:band]
    # Here I had to separate each string with white-space and put double quote around each
    inputImages = ' '.join('"' + x + '"' for x in inputTif)
    # Took the first image name (LT51370432006355BKT00_B1.TIF) so that I know it later
    outputImages = os.path.join(dir, inputTif[0])[:-7] + "_concat.tif"

    os.system('otbcli_ConcatenateImages -il %s -out "%s"' % (inputImages, outputImages))
    return

folderName = r"C:\Documents and Settings\Landsat_image"
concatLandsat(folderName)
```

Comment: `os.system` is [deprecated in favour of `subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) methods. `subprocess.call` for instance would solve your outputimages formating, since it takes a list and adds the spaces accordingly.

Comment: [the link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) says it's old but still not deprecated. Replacement will not be a problem though.

Comment: does that work as expected?

Comment: yes it did. Now I am testing samilar code for other tools of OTB and RSGISLIB

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is in the following line:

```
outputImages = os.path.join(root, tifFile) + '_concat.tif'
```

which returns something like: path/to/the/tifFile.tif_concat.tif

Instead, you need to strip the extension from the original file:

```
outputImages = os.path.join(root, tifFile)[:-4] + '_concat.tif'
```

**EDIT based on the comment**:
It looks you need to provide a list of input files and a **single** output file. In that case, change the code as following to create a list of input files in the loop but execute the command outside the loop:

```
import os
dir = "C:\Documents and Settings\Landsat_image"
def fileList():
    inputImages = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir):
        for tifFile in filenames:
            for i in range(3):
                if tifFile.find('B' + str(i)) != -1 and tifFile.endswith('.TIF'):
                    inputImages.append(os.path.join(dir, tifFile))
    outputImages = inputImages[0][:-4] + '_concat.tif'
    process = os.system(
    'otbcli_ConcatenateImages -il %s -out %s' % (inputImages, outputImages))
```

Comment: The canonical way to strip extensions is to use `os.path.splitext(path)[0]`. Hardcoding fails when the extension changes (see TIFF vs TIF, JPEG vs JPG, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the error still remains. How can I make one result for `outputImages` instead of many?

Comment: @Paul - agreed, but in the above case in the if statement the extension was hardcoded ('.TIF') therefore stripping the last four characters was safe.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to stack the first three bands of a Landsat scene into a single GeoTiff, as they are delivered as one file per band.

Here's an alternative to `os.walk` to get those files using `glob`. Since their filenames start with the band number we can just split the sorted list to the first 3 entries.

```
import os
import glob

landsat_dir = C:\Documents and Settings\Landsat_image'
file_list = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(landsat_dir, "*.tif")))[:3]
```

Now you can use `GDAL` to stack these into a single GeoTiff. One way would be to use the command line tools, `gdal_merge.py` in this case.

```
import subprocess

merge_cmd = ["gdal_merge.py", "-o", "stacked-output.tif", "-separate", file_list[0], file_list[1], file_list[2]]
subprocess.call(merge_cmd)
```